# Trying to migrate to Github from Bitbucket, getting file size error

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I'm trying to migrate from bitbucket to github. What I did was remove bitbucket from the remote and add  my github account instead. I then tried to `git push -u origin master` but I got a `large file detected` error and then a `this exceeds Github's file size limit of 100MB`.

I know which file is making the problem and I've deleted it a few commits ago but since it's still in previous commits it's still making problems.

How can I fix this?

Comment: there is a official guide from github[removing-files-from-a-repositorys-history](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/removing-files-from-a-repositorys-history). For me, I use Desktop app on windows. There is an `undo` button at leftbottom of `change` page. Click that works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GitHub places a [hard limit on the size of individual files](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files):

> GitHub warns you when you try to add a file larger than 50 MB. We'll reject pushes containing files larger than 100 MB.

If any commit in your repo contains that file, GitHub will not allow you to push to a remote repository hosted on their servers.

Your options?

1. Stay on Bitbucket, or
2. rewrite the history of your repo (using, for instance, [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), or Roberto Tyley's [BFG Repo-Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)) so that no file exceeding 100 Mb in size be present in **any** commit of that repo.

Answer (score 3):

Github allows only maximum 100MB file. I also got same error while migrating from Bitbucket to Github. 
Run command`sudo git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf /YOUR_PROJECT_LARGE_FILE_PATH' HEAD`:

It helped me to solve this issue. I got solution code from [here](https://www.studytutorial.in/git-error-how-to-remove-unwanted-large-file-from-git-commit-history).