# Git - How to remove a large file from commit history so I can push repository?

Tags: git, github

I've accidentally committed a directory that weighs around 100MB to my repository a few months back.

Fast forward to today, I'm trying to migrate that repo to Github. It won't let me because of a size limit.

I've removed that directory using the following post: [Completely remove file from all Git repository commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history)

It seemed to have worked however the entire project still weighs 100M. 
I've run `du .` and got the following line: `98M    ./.git/objects`.

I'm not sure how to fix this as I've tried a few solutions and none of them seemed to work.

What should I do now?

Edit: I managed to fix it using the thread I linked above. Specifically Darren's answer.

Comment: Try to run `git gc --prune=now`.

Comment: Didn't help. It's been reduced to 95MB (down from 99MB).

Comment: simular: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389155/trying-to-migrate-to-github-from-bitbucket-getting-file-size-error

Comment: try to add `--aggressive` to Gergo's command

Comment: @wolvercats - Didnt' help. Same situation

Comment: Is it possible you still have old branches around?

Comment: I don't have any branch other than `master`. Either way I've fixed it and added the solution to my question.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix it using the thread I linked above. Specifically I did something similar to Darren's answer. I'll put it here for your convenience:

> This is the best way:
>   http://github.com/guides/completely-remove-a-file-from-all-revisions
>
> Just be sure to backup the copies of the files first.
>
> **EDIT**
>
> The edit by [Neon][1] got unfortunately rejected during review.   See
>   Neons post below, it might contain useful information!
>
> [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/309261/neon
>
> ---
>
> E.g. to remove all `*.gz` files accidentally committed into git
>   repository:
>
> ```
> $ du -sh .git ==> e.g. 100M
> $ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch *.gz' HEAD
> $ git push origin master --force
> $ rm -rf .git/refs/original/
> $ git reflog expire --expire=now --all
> $ git gc --prune=now
> $ git gc --aggressive --prune=now
> ```
>
> That still didn't work for me? (I am currently at git version 1.7.6.1)
>
> ```
> $ du -sh .git ==> e.g. 100M
> ```
>
> Not sure why, since I only had ONE master branch. Anyways, I finally
>   got my git repo truely cleaned up by pushing into a new empty and bare
>   git repository, e.g.
>
> ```
> $ git init --bare /path/to/newcleanrepo.git
> $ git push /path/to/newcleanrepo.git master
> $ du -sh /path/to/newcleanrepo.git ==> e.g. 5M
> ```
>
> *(yes!)*
>
> Then I clone that to a new directory and moved over it's .git folder
>   into this one. e.g.
>
> ```
> $ mv .git ../large_dot_git
> $ git clone /path/to/newcleanrepo.git ../tmpdir
> $ mv ../tmpdir/.git .
> $ du -sh .git ==> e.g. 5M
> ```
>
> *(yeah! finally cleaned up!)*
>
> After verifying that all is well, then you can delete the
>   `../large_dot_git` and `../tmpdir` directories (maybe in a couple
>   weeks or month from now, just in case...)

In short: I filtered the branch, created a new bare repo, pushed the master to it, cloned it into a new directory and replaced my project's git directory with the git directory from the clone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `expire` entries in the reflog otherwise it will hold references to those old blobs, then `garbage collect` it.

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

If that doesn't work try the [BFG](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) tool to clean your repo. Do as they say, make a copy of the repository first.